# Conflicting omnibus results for a mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I am attempting to get omnibus tests of interactions with a multicategorical variable ("strategy") in mixed-effects models. When running this in `lmerTest::lmer`, I noticed that the results from `car::Anova` and `anova.lmerTest` differed in ways that suggest different conclusions (i.e., an effect that was nonsignificant with `Anova` was significant with `anova`).

Given that I am receiving different results from these functions, I am unsure what is most appropriate for this situation.

I expect small variations, especially using Ward chi-squared tests compared to an F test with Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite degrees of freedom. However, the differences I am seeing are larger than I'd expect and suggest different conclusions.

Here is the summary of the model:

For context:

- Data comes from an intensive longitudinal (ecological momentary assessment) study where individuals completed surveys over several days
- Group is a person-level factor
- Strategy is a multicategorical factor and repeated within survey (every row is a strategy per survey per day per person)
- The main variable of interest is the autoregressive slope of negative affect

```r
> summary(model)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: na.t2 ~ group * strategy * na + (na | id/day)
   Data: ema_long_refnone_std

REML criterion at convergence: 5237.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9441 -0.4330 -0.1505  0.2386  7.2226 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 day:id   (Intercept) 0.034712 0.18631       
          na          0.039280 0.19819  0.88 
 id       (Intercept) 0.225537 0.47491       
          na          0.006272 0.07919  -0.50
 Residual             0.354287 0.59522       
Number of obs: 2599, groups:  day:id, 503; id, 103

Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       -0.24685    0.07160   75.18233  -3.447  0.00093 ***
groupSZ                            0.53314    0.10524   77.90156   5.066 2.66e-06 ***
strategyreappraising               0.10582    0.10326 2398.36079   1.025  0.30558    
strategysharing                    0.07288    0.12775 2390.80108   0.570  0.56841    
strategyattention                  0.09886    0.10047 2397.50742   0.984  0.32524    
strategyavoiding                   0.11431    0.15337 2357.23408   0.745  0.45617    
strategyhiding                    -0.17877    0.17337 2362.62142  -1.031  0.30260    
na                                 0.22424    0.04090   89.46584   5.482 3.84e-07 ***
groupSZ:strategyreappraising      -0.17355    0.13489 2419.49560  -1.287  0.19837    
groupSZ:strategysharing           -0.13001    0.15574 2432.98603  -0.835  0.40392    
groupSZ:strategyattention         -0.18011    0.13435 2420.15624  -1.341  0.18017    
groupSZ:strategyavoiding          -0.20555    0.17882 2369.30664  -1.149  0.25048    
groupSZ:strategyhiding             0.17198    0.25925 2326.81740   0.663  0.50716    
groupSZ:na                         0.07377    0.05566   90.68751   1.326  0.18833    
strategyreappraising:na           -0.17487    0.12249 2060.50288  -1.428  0.15353    
strategysharing:na                -0.38368    0.12249 1990.48877  -3.132  0.00176 ** 
strategyattention:na              -0.17019    0.12635 2201.69278  -1.347  0.17812    
strategyavoiding:na               -0.19486    0.15403 2253.50623  -1.265  0.20598    
strategyhiding:na                 -0.15712    0.21971 2282.06633  -0.715  0.47460    
groupSZ:strategyreappraising:na    0.15704    0.13987 2167.65742   1.123  0.26167    
groupSZ:strategysharing:na         0.32126    0.13994 2094.83522   2.296  0.02179 *  
groupSZ:strategyattention:na       0.03436    0.14744 2273.55364   0.233  0.81576    
groupSZ:strategyavoiding:na        0.12592    0.16818 2279.34457   0.749  0.45410    
groupSZ:strategyhiding:na          0.07480    0.26795 2298.17673   0.279  0.78015    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and the omnibus tests:

```r
> # Anova Wald
> Anova(model, type = "III")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: na.t2
                    Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)       11.8848  1  0.0005659 ***
group             25.6659  1  4.059e-07 ***
strategy           3.7701  5  0.5829610    
na                30.0546  1  4.200e-08 ***
group:strategy     4.7006  5  0.4535018    
group:na           1.7570  1  0.1850037    
strategy:na       11.8744  5  0.0365499 *  
group:strategy:na  5.8978  5  0.3162926    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> # Anova Kenward-Roger
> Anova(model, type = "III", test.statistic = "F")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)

Response: na.t2
                        F Df  Df.res    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)       11.8073  1   99.84 0.0008612 ***
group             25.5020  1  105.01 1.871e-06 ***
strategy           0.7499  5 2344.18 0.5860915    
na                28.6949  1   76.67 8.590e-07 ***
group:strategy     0.9312  5 2363.35 0.4594962    
group:na           1.6853  1   75.60 0.1981660    
strategy:na        2.3227  5 2165.96 0.0408497 *  
group:strategy:na  1.1599  5 2237.36 0.3266031    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> # anova Satterthwaite (lmerTest default)
> anova(model, type = "III")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
group             4.4889  4.4889     1  153.09 12.6701 0.0004952 ***
strategy          0.2425  0.0485     5 2305.85  0.1369 0.9837937    
na                3.8407  3.8407     1  395.87 10.8408 0.0010821 ** 
group:strategy    1.6654  0.3331     5 2305.85  0.9401 0.4537256    
group:na          1.8069  1.8069     1  395.87  5.1002 0.0244674 *  
strategy:na       4.8255  0.9651     5 2165.85  2.7241 0.0184565 *  
group:strategy:na 2.0895  0.4179     5 2165.85  1.1796 0.3166858    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> # anova Kenward-Roger
> anova(model, type = "III", ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
group             4.4554  4.4554     1  206.38 12.5756 0.0004836 ***
strategy          0.2409  0.0482     5 2363.35  0.1360 0.9840286    
na                3.7434  3.7434     1  321.57 10.5659 0.0012739 ** 
group:strategy    1.6496  0.3299     5 2363.35  0.9312 0.4594962    
group:na          1.7611  1.7611     1  321.57  4.9708 0.0264686 *  
strategy:na       4.7321  0.9464     5 2237.36  2.6711 0.0205179 *  
group:strategy:na 2.0548  0.4110     5 2237.36  1.1599 0.3266031    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

While most results are consistent, the `group:na` interaction is different in `anova.lmerTest` compared to `car::Anova` in both cases for each. One thing that sticks out to me is that the residual/denominator degrees of freedom are comparable for omnibus tests of only categorical variables but are very different for `na` and `group:na`.

Any thoughts on what might be driving this or which test would be most appropriate to report/act on?